# SQL Server 2017 Express Faster than standard Edition

Tags: sql-server

What could explain SQL server Express edition to be much faster than web / standard edition.

These are multiple VM in could hosting.
They all experience the same Problem.
some are on SQL Server 2012 other on 2017 same problem. all machine have latest updates.

Machine are good enough for the job 8G 4 cores and DBs are small in size less than 1GB of data.
Same machines. I even tried have both Express and Wed edition on the same machine 
with only one instance enabled at a time, same problem.

It does not matter if the web application is run locally in the same machine or remotely accessing SQL sever though network, same problem.

The DBs have Exactly the same data.

queries are multiple in forms and complexities all run half the speed in web edition.

It is not specific to Web edition and the type of server as this was replicated on development machines on Express VS developer edition.

SQL Server setting appear to be the same.

Multiple people have looked at it and we cannot figure out why.

any help appreciated

Comment: You should try asking this on dba.stackexchange.com, but make sure you include an example query with execution plans from both environments to give them something to go on.  There is not enough information to even guess what the problem might be at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, done on dba.stackexchange.com. This would be a general concept question. Execution plan are exactly the same.